# Hiding An Img in AngularJS Based on Model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

First, I've looked through other questions and not found an answer.

I have a custom directive with a two attributes: `multiValue` and `ngModel`. Both of these values are represented in the controller as `$scope.multiValue` and `$scope.ngModel`.

The behavior of the directive changes based on the value of `$scope.ngModel`. In both cases, the directive creates an input and an image:

```
<input id="{{controlId}}" name="{{controlId}}" placeholder="Select Value(s)" 
    class="k-textbox" type="text" ng-model="ngModel" />
<img ng-src="/img/X.png" ng-click="clear()" 
    ng-show="multiValue == false && ngModel === ''" />
```

The purpose of the image is to show an "X" icon to clear the value represented by `$scope.ngModel`. However, when `$scope.multiValue` is true, the X icon does not need to display. When `$scope.multiValue` is false and a value has been selected, the X icon needs to display.

I have tried multiple means to get the X to disappear when multiValue is false or a value has not yet been selected:

- Tried both "src" and "ng-src"
- Tried combinations of ng-if and ng-show (including the ones above)
- Tried using the condition ability of ng-src to define the image to show based on the same condition shown in the prior example.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So shouldn't it be `ng-show="!multiValue && ngModel.length"` ?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please use `<ng-if="">` Instead of `<ng-show="">`.

I am not sure of is this helpful. But I have faced similar issues that time I used `<ng-if="">`

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned about which version of Angular you are using.

However, in Angular 6 or 7 you can use

> `*ngIf="multiValue == false && ngModel === ''"`

Hope this will help you

Comment: Using AngularJS.

Comment: Here is a link for you https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Comment: @KrishnaRaniSahoo Questions tagged with [tag:angularjs] are for version **1.x only** so your answer is irrelevant (Unless you use Angularjs native directives)